# What "a foot or so" mean?

Tags: expressions

I saw a sentence like "Some coastal waters and rivers can have such a high concentration of suspended sediment and floating plant material that light only penetrates surface a foot or so" In this sentence, is "a foot or so" meaning as "a little bit"?

Comment: What research have you done to answer this question yourself? Please tell us what it is you don't understand about what you have read? If you were unable to find anything, what did you google? Please take the tour: https://english.stackexchange.com/tour and take a look through the help centre to familiarise yourself with our ways: https://english.stackexchange.com/help  You might consider joining our sister site for English language learners here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: "A foot, more or less."  "About a foot."  "On the order of a foot".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

A foot is a measure of distance equal to 12 inches or roughly 30 centimeters. So this sentence says that because the water is so murky and full of debris, light penetrates **approximately** ("or so") that distance.